# hibernate query language

Tags: hibernate, hql

**please convert the sql in hql**

**SQL Statement** : s*elect username from useraccout where email = "parameter value"*

**More description:**

while running the code i am getting this error:

```
public  List dispUser(String email){
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT u.username FROM Useraccout u WHERE u.email=:email)");
    query.setParameter(email, email);
    List search = query.getResultList();
    return search;
}
```

**while running the code i am getting following error**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
Useraccout is not mapped [SELECT u.username FROM Useraccout u WHERE u.email=:email1)]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:624)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:96)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
```

Comment: -1 for the wrong topic - please read the Hibernate documentation before using it. A good starting point would be http://hibernate.org/152.html . Hint: you have to map the classes in Hibernate configuration before using them.

Comment: "useraccout", you sure you didn't just make a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you haven't mapped a class named `Useraccount`. My guess is that either:

- You've mapped a class named `Useraccount` and have typed the name of this class incorrectly in the query
- You haven't mapped any classes. This indicates that you don't understand the basics of Hibernate. In short, every class that maps to a database table needs to define this mapping using either an XML file or annotations.